# Convert JSON Array to Object Node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this array :

```
[   { nom: 'fusion', nbrRune: 1 },
    { nom: 'air', nbrRune: 2 },
    { nom: 'earth', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'fire', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'life', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'logic', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'water', nbrRune: 0 }
]
```

and I want to convert it in object like this:

```
{ nom: 'fusion', nbrRune: 1 },
{ nom: 'air', nbrRune: 2 },
{ nom: 'earth', nbrRune: 0 },
{ nom: 'fire', nbrRune: 0 },
{ nom: 'life', nbrRune: 0 },
{ nom: 'logic', nbrRune: 0 },
{ nom: 'water', nbrRune: 0 }
```

Can you help me to convert it? Thanks.

Comment: The structure you describe isn't **an** object.

Comment: Ok but I want to convert my array in the other structure.

Comment: It isn't **a** structure either. It is multiple things. You would need something to hold them… like an array… which brings you back to where you started.

Comment: please double check what structure you need. You cant convert array to format you posted.

Comment: I see an array in the first case, and a series of objects in the second. What exactly do you want?

Comment: There is nothing node-specific about this. I suggest you read up on rudimentary Array operations, which are pretty common to most languages and see where that leads you. Your suggested resulting structure is not a storable structure as one unit. That result would require 7 variables for each extracted object and as mentioned, an array would be the ideal storage unit for them either way.

Comment: I want to return a JSON 'Thing' but not an array I just want all the object like I show below.

Comment: The thing is that I build an array with the database because it's more easy but I need to return it withought the [ ] to be used like an object list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be trying to do this?

```
var myObj = {};

var myArr = [   
    { nom: 'fusion', nbrRune: 1 },
    { nom: 'air', nbrRune: 2 },
    { nom: 'earth', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'fire', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'life', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'logic', nbrRune: 0 },
    { nom: 'water', nbrRune: 0 }
];

myObj.stuff = myArr;

alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d90Lkcgs/

This will give you an object that contains an array of objects.

Things within curly braces are objects. Things within square brackets are arrays.

Comment: This is not exacly what I need. I don't want the stuff:[...] just {...},{...},...

Comment: You can't have that in JavaScript. If you have commas between objects, you need to hold them in an array. If you need an object that holds other objects, you need an object with an array inside, like in my example. I added some more info to my answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my example is what you're looking for. Show the place that processes the data, and it would be easier to answer your question. There is no practical way, that I know of, to send back a list of objects without putting them in an array, unless you want to do them one at a time.

Comment: It's for an Android app. This is the JSON that my API return and the Android app will loop in all of the object to show the information.

Comment: I'll use your solution and I'll try things

Comment: A JavaScript object is made up of key-value pairs. The values can be other objects or other arrays (or strings, etc.). I don't know Java, but you should be able to get the {"stuff": [{...}, {...}, {...}]} and loop through each item of the array of objects in "stuff". See the phone example here -- maybe that would help: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html